# For how many different ways, can you give three children 12 apples and one pear so they can have at least one fruit?

Tags: combinatorics

For how many different ways, can you give three children 12 apples and one pear so they can have at least one fruit? We can't tell the difference between apples.

Comment: What did you try to solve this? Where did you got stuck? Add that to the question.

Comment: If you have ever lived or worked with children, you should know that there is only one solution: each child gets four apples, and you eat the pear yourself.

Comment: @EnemyPanda What you are saying in your comment should be added to your question. This to avoid downvotes and to increase the animo to answer your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:** Break the problem into two.

How many distinct ways can you give 13 apples to three children so each child has at least one?  (Hint: put the apples in a line and select ways to divide it into three portions.)

Having done so, how many distinct ways can you then swap one apple for one pear?

Comment: I can divide 13 apples between three children in ${12\choose 2}$ ways

Comment: @EnemyPanda Yes, that is so. You are selecting $k$ things from $n$; but *what* are you selecting and from *where*? [Update:] Looks like you worked out you are selecting $2$ spaces from $12$ between the apples.

Comment: I put 13 apples in line and I am trying to count in how many ways I can put bars between them. I have 12 places between apples and I need to divide them (I mean that line) for 3 parts

Comment: And I swap one apple for one pear so I got $3 \cdot {12\choose 2}$ ways.

Comment: Now I should add ways where child got only one pear and in my opinion it should be $3 \cdot {12\choose 2} + 3 \cdot {12\choose 1}$

Comment: @EnemyPanda  No, you were right the first time. There are $\binom{12}{2}$ ways to divide thirteen apples among three children such that each child gets at least one, and there are $3$ distinct ways to select one child to swap an apple for a pear. Thus  $3\cdot\binom{12}{2}$ distinct ways to divide twelve apples and one pear among the three children such that each gets at least one piece of fruit.

Comment: Now, *among these*, there are $3\cdot \binom{11}{1}$ ways one child will receive only the pear; but we don't need to count these *again*.

Comment: ahhh yes, big thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slightly different approach:

1) First select the child to receive the pear.  Then give an apple to each of the other children.

2) Next distribute the remaining 10 apples to the children.

Now multiply the number of ways to perform step 1 and step 2.